# Cant get map preview to load in Watchkit 6.2 Beta using Swift

Tags: xcode, google-maps, maps, watchkit

I can't seem to get my map to load in Xcode 6.2 Beta, it just sticks on the spinning icon. Currently I have the following code in my Map interface controller:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class MapInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

  @IBOutlet weak var LocationMap: WKInterfaceMap!

  override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
      super.awakeWithContext(context)

      var centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.505248, -0.113838)

      self.LocationMap.setVisibleMapRect(MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPointForCoordinate(centerLocation), size: MKMapSizeMake(0.5, 0.5)))

      self.LocationMap.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)))

  }

}
```

Which then causes my map to not load properly and I end up with the spinning loading icon which never fully loads.

I'm sure I'm probably just missing something obvious as I'm fairly new to all this, but I can't seem to find any resources at all that will show me what I'm missing, or talk me through this process to help me see exactly what I've overlooked.

Comment: I ran into this same problem recently. It had seemingly randomly fixed itself around the time that I re-wired up the map outlet as a sanity check, but then when I reset the iOS Simulator for a different reason, this problem resurfaced. Did you ever sort it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have nearly the same code and it works fine for me. A few remarks:

`setRegion` sets the center coordinate as well as the visible map region so there is no need to call `setVisibleMapRect` prior.

Your properties and variables should not start with a capital letter (although this is not the cause of the problem)

Here is the code I use:

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: 51.505248,
    longitude: -0.113838)
)

let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
self.map.setRegion(region)
```

Comment: Thank you that's definitely cleaned things up for me! but I'm still unable to get the map to load, It renders the app, and the functionality is fine throughout except when I get to the map screen it remains on the spinning icon like [this](http://postimg.org/image/qf7yfvlmp/), is there perhaps something that needs to be done in the setup? API related maybe?

Comment: It's still beta. Try a clean build and delete derived data

Comment: You were right, the code eventually caused the map to load (although not the regions specified by coordinates, but im going to put that down to the simulator) must have been a bug due to it being Beta, so I guess if the map area appears to be trying to load and xcode finds no errors, then all is fine even if you can't see it in the simulator, but we got there in the end!